# FAKE: CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo has difficulties with German umlauts

Tags: f#, f#-fake

When I'm using german umlauts in values for attributes they are converted into garbage.

```
Target "AssemblyInfo" (fun _ ->
    CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo "./src/App1/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"
        [
            Attribute.Title       "App1"
            Attribute.Product     "some umlauts: äüö"
        ]
)
```

When the build is completed I find something like this in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyProductAttribute("some umlauts: ���")]
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: it's probably a problem with the encoding (of your script) (note: *I did never try*) - can you try and change the encoding and see what it'll produce? If not that's probably a good candidate for a bug-ticket on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by replacing the umlaut characters with there corresponding unicode codes:

```
Attribute.Product "some umlauts: \u00e4\u00fc\u00f6"
```

**Update**

Using Unicode characters definitely works but the real cause was an encoding problem. After changing the encoding of the build script to UTF-8 the umlauts were translated correctly. (Thanks to @Carsten and @mthierba)

Comment: I've had that same problem before, and as @Carsten suggested, it occurred because the FAKE script file was saved with ANSI encoding rather than UTF-8.

Comment: @Carsten and mthierba: Both of you are right. It was indeed an encoding problem. Post it as an answer and I will give the first one the credits.

Comment: Carsten and @mthierba: Both of you are right. It was indeed an encoding problem. Post it as an answer and I will give the first one the credits.